# Displaying count of duplicates and removing duplicates at the same time?

Tags: sql, oracle, count, duplicates

Apologies if the title doesn't make full sense, I'll try to explain as best I can.

I have a table containing information about vehicles, there are many duplicates and around 5000 rows overall. Here's a snippet as an example:

[image]

As you can see the model '159 TI TBI' repeats twice, this essentially means there are two of these cars stored in London.

I am looking for something like below, where there is a count of how many times a particular vehicle in a particular location repeats, as well as removing duplicates so each vehicle only appears once for each location.

[image]

I am able to do a fairly simple select command for a particular vehicle and location, such as

```
SELECT COUNT(model), model, loc_name, vehicle_type
FROM vehicles
WHERE loc_name='London' AND model='159 TI TBI'
GROUP BY model, loc_name, vehicle_type
```

The issue is that I'd be repeating this command for *every* combination of a vehicle model in a particular location, it's not very efficient.

Hopefully this makes some sense, I haven't had a huge amount of experience with SQL so apologies if anything is badly wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Simply skip the WHERE clause. Done!

Comment: Is your question strictly about producing a report with this information, or are you looking to change the data stored in the table? If it's just for reporting, jarlh (in the comment above) and TheName (in an Answer) have already provided the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you the required results

```
 SELECT COUNT(model) cnt, model, loc_name, vehicle_type
   FROM vehicles
  GROUP BY model, loc_name, vehicle_type
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't realise it would be this simple!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear.  But let me try.  It seems you think to get the count for each group, you would have to re-query with for each vehicle in the where clause.  However, aggregation will allow you to get the count across all the vehicles.  If you are just looking for the model, location, type uniquely and the count of occurrences, you have the right query, just remove your where clause and the power of SQL will take care of it for you.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as quantity, model, loc_name, vehicle_type 
FROM vehicles
GROUP BY model, loc_name, vehicle_type
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want only the rows  with more then one occurrence you can  use having for filter th aggregated  result

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) as quantity, model, loc_name, vehicle_type 
 FROM vehicles
 GROUP BY model, loc_name, vehicle_type
 having count(*) > 1
```